# Javascript audio starts very low on chrome.. It works fine on edge

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio

I'm working on my sandbox game and I started adding some sound effects..

The problem is, that the audio works fine on Edge, but when I'm trying it on chrome or opera the audio for (and only for) dirt starts very low and after few repeated plays of this sound effect it gets on normal sound volume (dirt0.volume always shows 1).. On edge it starts normally loud. Other sound effects are working fine even on chrome but i noticed that the speed of repeating is a lot faster on chrome than on edge.. i din't know why but I want them to be equal on every browser..

I'm loading sound effects normally
like this:

```
grass0 = new Audio('grass0.wav');

grass1 = new Audio('grass1.wav');

dirt0 = new Audio('dirt0.wav');

dirt1 = new Audio('dirt1.wav');

wood0 = new Audio('wood0.wav');

wood1 = new Audio('wood1.wav');

and then im just playing them by using .play() if none
of the other sound effects are playing.

if(grass0.paused & grass1.paused & dirt0.paused & dirt1.paused & wood0.paused & wood1.paused){

if(blocks[i].id == 1){ //Blok [1]

if(audio[0] == 0){

grass0.play();

audio[0] = 1;

}else{

grass1.play();

audio[0] = 0;

}

}else if(blocks[i].id == 2){ //Blok [2]

if(audio[1] == 0){

dirt0.play();

audio[1] = 1;

}else{

dirt1.play();

audio[1] = 0;

}

}else if(blocks[i].id == 7){ //Blok [7]

if(audio[2] == 0){

wood0.play();

audio[2] = 1;

}else{

wood1.play();

audio[2] = 0;

}

}

}

..
```

Look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHPQGnqFr8E) video for better understanding.

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting the volume?

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: `Audio` objects have a `volume` property that can be set to manually change the volume of the sound.

Comment: i said that (dirt0.volume always shows 1)..